# Form dialog don't set state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dialog, event-handling, setstate

I have created a simple login function where once the user log in, he is redirect to another page. Then I wanted to change the login form with a form dialog. And the problem is here. The login dialog works, but when I enter the username and password, I'm not send to another page but to the same login page :/.

Here is the code:

Login.jsx:

```
class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      islogged: false,
      loginSettings: {
        lUsername: "",
        lPassword: ""
      }
    };
  }

  handleInput = (event) => {
    let loginSettingsNew = { ...this.state.loginSettings };
    let val = event.target.value;
    loginSettingsNew[event.target.name] = val;
    this.setState({
      loginSettings: loginSettingsNew
    });
  };

  login = (event) => {
    let lUsername = this.state.loginSettings.lUsername;
    let lPassword = this.state.loginSettings.lPassword;
    if (lUsername === "admin" && lPassword === "password") {
      localStorage.setItem("token", "T");
      this.setState({
        islogged: true
      });
    } else {
      console.log("Erreur");
    }
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  render() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("token")) {
      return <Redirect to="/" />;
    }
    return (
      <div className="Login">
        <Dialog handleInput={this.handleInput} login={this.login} />
        <p>Username: admin - Password: password</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Dialog.js:

```
export default function FormDialog() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
        Open form dialog
      </Button>
      <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
        <DialogTitle>Login</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <form onSubmit={this.login}>
            <label>
              <span>Username</span>
              <input name="lUsername" type="text" onChange={this.handleInput} />
            </label>
            <label>
              <span>Password</span>
              <input name="lPassword" type="password" onChange={this.handleInput}/>
            </label>
            <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">Cancel</Button>
            <Button type="submit" value="submit" color="primary">Login</Button>
          </form>
        </DialogContent>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I also have created a sandbox of my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-login-auth-forked-r06ht

I thinks that the problem come from the form dialog that can't set the state of `islogged` of the login function. I tried quite a lot of things but nothing worked, so I would like to ask some help please.

I thank in advance anyone who will take the time to help me .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I notice that your `Login` component is a class, while the child `FormDialog` component is a function component using Hooks. There's nothing wrong with that, in itself - particularly if you started with an application using all class components and are slowly converting your components. But I detect some confusion here, because your function component seems to assume it's a class, in a sense. When you need to do things a bit differently.

Specifically, you reference `this.login` in your function component - but this is meaningless. `login` is passed in as a prop. In a class component, you would reference it as `this.props.login`. This doesn't work in a function component - but `this.login` isn't the substitute. Indeed `this` will tend to be `undefined` so this would even give an error. Even if not, it's not correct.

All you need to do is to make use of the argument to your function component - this is where the `props` object "lives" in a function component. You happen to ignore it by not using any arguments - but you don't have to do this.

So in short, what you need to do is:

1. replace `export default function FormDialog()` with `export default function FormDialog(props)`
2. replace `this.login` with `props.login`
3. repeat 2) for all other props which you have referenced using `this`

Comment: They avoided the helpful "property of undefined" error because the component is declared using the `function` keyword` and `this` refers to `window`. If they had used an arrow function it would have broke instead making it much easier to track down.

Comment: Even then, `this` would only be `window` outside of strict mode. I thought ES6 modules (clearly in use here due to the `export default`) enforced strict mode - but it's not something I know too much about, just thought I'd seen it somewhere. (To be clear, you *should* be using strict mode everywhere, even if you have to deliberately put `use strict`, it's like having a slightly saner subset of JS.)

Answer (score 1):

Ok all fixed. In your App.js you didn't have a home component to redirect to with this path="/". I've created a new component called home.js. Tidied the Routes for you.

```
<Route path="/login" component={Login} />
<ProtectedRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
```

Please check ur code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/react-login-auth-forked-24m8e?file=/src/App.js